# PHP error after moving Codeigniter to server

Tags: php, imagick

For a client of us, we have moved the website to our server. Everything went well with the move except for one page. When you go to this page. I get this error

[image]

How can I solve this?

Maybe good to know, so I am not an expert.

Greetz,
Remy

Comment: did you changed base url after moving site to new server

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo`. Can you see `Imagick` module is loaded and enabled correctly?

Comment: @shasi yes i did.

Comment: @mrorno where can I check these things.. :)

Comment: @Comlap Create page on your server that just have `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and open it with your browser. You can check loaded modules there.